# Authorization Bearer Access token is not getting auto populated in API console of WSO2 API MANAGER store

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

PFB details:

1. I am using Identity server as key manager setup with WSO2 API Manager.
2. I have created application in WSO2 STORE and generated production and sandbox key successfully.
3. I have subscribed APIs with that application.
4. But Authorization bearer token in not visible in WSO2 STORE API Console.
   Attaching Images.

Note: SAME is working in my other environment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VALe2.png

Comment: Have u generated keys for default application? Can u verify that?

Comment: Did you subscribe the API through the Default Application and did you generate a production access token for Default application?

Comment: Were you able to check whether you created keys for the default application? What is the difference between other environments?